# Stop media player in a View on Android

Tags: android, view, media

Because of my project, I have to use Media Player in a thread of a View (not an Activity). But the problem is I don't know how to stop it when the back button is pressed.

So is there anyway to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pls paste your `code` what you have did....

Answer (score 0):

No matter what your using the Views **post()** method that your calling the (running on Views thread) both of them using Main thread you can called UI thread.

Within android developer block they have explain when we have to release the resource and how can release the resources...

Explore **MediaPlayer **
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

You simply have to use :

```
mp.stop();
```